# Getting unexplained error in tkinter when using .get() for entry widget: 'Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback..'

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I am trying to get the user's entered text from an entry box in tkinter. Whenever I do so using the following code I get an unexplained error. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
e = ''
def g():
    word = e.get()
    T.insert(word)
    e.delete(0, END)
T = Text(root)
T.pack()
e = Entry(root, bg= 'blue', textvariable = e, fg= 'white')
e.pack()
e.bind('<Return>', g)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549,
in __call__
    return self.func(*args) TypeError: g() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: i got this code from a reliable website (effbot.org). this is the code i have seen for this task almost everywhere.

Comment: Remove `textvariable=e` as it is not needed when you use `widget.get()` and would raise an exception if you did use it.  A text variable must be an instance of StringVar.

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger a callback via a keypress (like a keyboard or mouse button), it sends an event to the callback. This event object contains information like the button that was pressed, the coordinates of the mouse click, that sort of thing. To fix this, make your function account for an event (or a potential event with a default parameter):

```
def g(event=None):
```